# VLOOKUP TRUE ISSUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am building an RFM table in excel, and want to lookup against a score table I created. Using row 3 as an example in the pic below, when I use the vlookup true function which is supposed to return a close match from the recency rankings table the vlookup is pulling in a 5 in column F, instead of a 1. I am not looking to do an exact match as that is not how this analysis is structured.

Any thoughts on why the true statement in the vlookup is not returning correct values? Any thoughts on how to fix would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blS3h.png)

Comment: If your version of excel supports then use `XLOOKUP()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use TRUE as the final parameter in VLOOKUP (for "approximate match"), Excel (for whatever reason) stipulates that the corresponding values in the first column of the lookup range must be in ascending order.  The prompt as you're typing the formula notes this

[image: Screenshot showing formula hint about sort order of lookup range values]

Therefore, re-order your lookup table and then the VLOOKUP values should populate as you expect them to